How to fix "Cannot find" inside cellForRowAt method?
I'm using this code to call an action when a button inside a cell is clicked:
class FavoritesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FavoritesCell", for: indexPath) as! FavoritesCell

        cell.copyCall = { cell in
            let copy = UIPasteboard.general
            copy.string = "\(titleL) - \(translation)"
        }

        return cell
    }
}

But I have this error :
Cannot find 'titleL' in scope
Cannot find 'translation' in scope

Although I add titleL and translation inside table cell class
If I use this code outside cell.copyCall = { cell in all works fine
class FavoritesCell: UITableViewCell {
var copyCall : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

var title: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

var translation: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

    @objc func copyButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        copyButton.imageView?.addSymbolEffect(.bounce.down, options: .nonRepeating, animated: true, completion: { _ in
            self.copyButton.imageView?.removeAllSymbolEffects()
        })
        copyCall?(self)
    }
}


Can you add code of copyCall ?

@ShehataGamal added to question

Where is delcared titleL? And translation?

@Larme added to question

This is code from an iOS app. You should add the iOS tag to the question.

Change
var copyCall : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

to
var copyCall : ((FavoritesCell) -> Void)?

Then
copy.string = "\(cell.title.text!) - \(cell.translation.text!)"

